# Still trying to get my head around に and で

Tags: word-choice, に-and-で

I've been trying to understand those two particles when applied to these phrases:

> 1. 私は朝ご飯にお茶を飲みます
> 2. 私は朝ご飯でお茶を飲みます
> 3. 私は朝ご飯の時にお茶を飲みます

What I more or less understand is:

> 1. the only/main thing I have for breakfast
> 2. at breakfast time, but not at any other time
> 3. at breakfast time, but not restricted to that time.

So, my questions are:

- What general function does に fulfill in sentence 1 (specific time, direction...)?
- Is, in sentence 1, 朝ご飯 functioning as a time expression?
- In sentence 2,  is 朝ご飯 functioning as a time expression and じ indicating a restrictive period of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sentence 1, に is not functioning as a time expression. It's like *for* or *as*. "I have green tea **for** breakfast."

で when used as a time particle can indicate:

1. the age at which something was done: ２５歳で日本に行きました。*At the age of 25 I went to Japan.*
2. the end point of a period of time: １時間で宿題を終えた。*I finished my homework in/after an hour.*
   Neither of these apply in sentence 2 so 朝ごはん is not functioning as a time expression. The で is showing that 朝ごはん is the place/setting where the tea-drinking is taking place.

In sentence 3, 朝ごはん itself is not a time expression, but together with 時 (とき not じ）you get 朝ごはんの時 'the time of breakfast' or 'breakfast time'.

> Only one doubt I have: what does に indicate in the first sentence?

In sentence 1 に means *for* or *as*. It functions like として.

Comment: Thx for the answer, its clearer now to me.  Only one doubt I have: what does に indicate in the first sentence?  The event where the verb takes place?

Comment: Is it normal to use に in that context?  Or would 私は朝ご飯としてお茶を飲みます　be more common?

Comment: Yes it's more common to say "朝ごはんに" than "朝ごはんとして". The latter is natural, but somewhat emphasizes the nuance of *as*. (cf. 「食事としてではなく、おやつとしてピザを食べる」)

Comment: As far as sentence 3 is concerned, does not に apply as a time marker only when time can get quantified into digits, like 15th April, 3 o clock, Christmas (which has a specified date). Whereas, breakfast time, is more like today, yesterday etc. Which does not have a quantifiable duration ?