# 朝ご飯は vs. 朝ご飯に - difference between these two sentences?

Tags: nuances, particle-に, particle-は

I wanted to ask my language partner what he ate for breakfast. However, I was unsure whether what I said was correct despite him telling me that it's good - I would just like some verification.

I said:

> 朝ご飯は何を食べましたか。

I'm unsure whether this is "correct" as in is this how one would normally ask another person what they ate for breakfast?

The Google-translated equivalent is:

> (あなたは)朝食に何を食べたのですか？

I don't like to rely heavily on Google-translated sentences to verify if what I mean/say is correct. What is the difference (if any) between these two sentences and is what I said grammatically correct?

Comment: I'm sure Google took the "for" and translated it to に.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 朝ご飯は何を食べましたか。

This is correct. You're literally saying, "As for breakfast, what did you eat?"

> 朝食に何を食べたのですか？

Google is using the particle に to indicate *at* in a similar manner to that of 今週末に (this weekend), however, に is usually omitted for relative times. They're both grammatically correct. "At breakfast, what did you eat?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me better understand this. I just have to ask , what is the common way (formally) of asking what did you have for breakfast?

Comment: I think both に and は forms are common. I might use は myself.
Aside from that, usually using 熟語{じゅくご} are more formal than not. So in that case, using 朝食{ちょうしょく}.

Comment: @user224579 I agree. In this case に is "for" or "as", the only particle to fit in this sentence. は is omission (contraction?) of には.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17784/9831