# For dinner I ate

Tags: english-to-japanese

How would you say for dinner in Japanese would you say 
Bangohan no tame ni?
Or is that only for verbs for a person

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17784/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20971/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65187/9831

Answer (score 6):

ために means "for the sake of...", so it can't be used in this context. Here, you could use a simple construction with は.
For example: ばんごはんは、ラーメンを食べました。(I ate Ramen for dinner.)

Answer (score 1):

Just に can also be used. Like "as/for something" ばんごはんにカレーを食べた。(I ate curry for dinner)