# I have porridge for breakfast

Tags: syntax

みなさん!

I'm supposed to prepare a small speech for an oral exam I have on Monday based on the meals of the day. I'm just a bit confused as to what the correct structure would be;

1. 私は朝ごはんにオートミールを食べます。
2. 朝ごはんはオートミールをたべます。

And a side question porridge = オートミール ?

The doubt I have is that our 先生 hasn't taught us the grammar for the first phrase, so I'm not sure he'd be happy with me using that one. Cheers in advance guys!

ありがとうございます!

Comment: I've never had porridge, but I'm not aware of anywhere in America where "oatmeal" and "porridge" are the same thing.  Maybe other countries?  Anyway, お[粥]{かゆ} is what I know as the word for "porridge" in Japanese, but every definition I see says it's "rice porridge".

Comment: Hey thanks for replying istrasci. Interesting, I actually did try to make rice porridge once, grinding the rice and heating it with milk, it just wasn't the same haha. Porridge is traditionally made with oats and milk or water, to my knowledge oatmeal is the same thing thing, just the American name, could be wrong though.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17783/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For porridge where it is assumed that it is 'oatmeal porridge', オートミール would be fine. Porridge and オートミール are not synonymous though.

Porridge as a general, all-encompassing term is ポリッジ.
Rice porridge is 粥｛かゆ｝, or more commonly お粥｛おかゆ｝.

> （私は）朝ごはんはオートミールを食べます。For breakfast, I eat oatmeal (porridge).
>   （私は）朝ごはんはポリッジを食べます。For breakfast, I eat (unspecified) porridge.
>   （私は）朝ごはんはお粥を食べます。For breakfast, I eat rice porridge.

Don't be overly concerned about the above sentences using two は particles.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Just what I needed to hear thanks. And thanks for the added information about the porridge.

Comment: So, following the same formula I could say, for example " 昨日, 昼ごはんはベイクドポテトを食べました。"?  ありがとうございます

Comment: @KaneyDudey Yes. That would work fine. I should mention that your use of に instead of は (after 朝ごはん) is not incorrect. It shifts the focus more towards what was eaten rather than when it was eaten, but functionally the sentences will be the same.  -As an unsolicited side note, when making requests and trying to convey a 'thanks in advance' sentiment, I would recommend using よろしくおねがいします rather than ありがとうございます.

Comment: Unsolicited side note much appreciated!